# Conditional Position Property of Navbar Component not Working in Tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, css-position, tailwind-ui

I am trying to show and hide a navbar based on whether a variable is set to true or false. I am able to get the Navbar to show/hide however, my problem happens when I try to set the Navbar to always show at the large breakpoint.

In other words, I want the navbar to be constantly showing at the large breakpoint and above even if the variable controlling the navbar is set to false. However, this does not happen. I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. Can someone please help me?

My code is here:

```
 <div className={`lg:!relative z-50 ${showNavBar ? "absolute" : "hidden"} `}>
      <Navbar showNavBar={showNavBar} handleNavBar={handleNavBar} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the `display: none` applied by `hidden` when `showNavBar` is falsy by using a [`display`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display) utility, like `block` for `display: block`:

```js
function Navbar() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      Foo
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const showNavBar = false;
const handleNavBar = null;

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(
  <div className={`lg:!relative lg:block z-50 ${showNavBar ? "absolute" : "hidden"} `}>
    <Navbar showNavBar={showNavBar} handleNavBar={handleNavBar} />
  </div>
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix the variables inside the brackets with "[max-lg](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#targeting-a-breakpoint-range)" so they only apply below the large breakpoint:

```
<div class={`lg:absolute ${showNavBar ? "max-lg:hidden" : "max-lg:absolute"} `}>
      <Navbar showNavBar={showNavBar} handleNavBar={handleNavBar} />
</div>
```